# Angular Jasmine How to test if () return; in a function

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I intent to test a function as below:

```
myFunction(input) {
  if (...) {
    return;
  } else {
    do something
  }
}
```

How to test the condition is return?

```
it('should', async(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'myFunction')
  // ????
}));
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are asking how to test that the function runs the `else` part, why not test that it *did something* (e.g. if it is calling a method, spy on that method and check that it was called).

Comment: sorry, I may not ask the question accurately. I wan to test the if part not else part

Comment: I guess you can safely say the *if* part was executed by testing that the *else* part was **not** executed.

Answer (score 2):

> How to test if () return; in a function

You don't using spy to determine the inside of the a function. You spy on arguments and return values. You can use spy on to determine if the function returns `undefined` (the implicit value for `return;`) for a given input.

If you want to know that *a particular* line return got tested, you need to use coverage reports.

Comment: I realize your point, but the condition just for break illegal input. Regardless of the response will always undefined, because the function doesn't return value, beside the condition for break this function.

Answer (score 1):

Without actual code it's hard to write a code sample for you to use. If you want to test the return of the function of the `if` part the logic will be something like this:

1. Manipulate the variables inside the if test so they evaluate to true. This may require the use of spies depending on what's inside the if test.
2. Inside an `it` block have something like `expect(component.myFunction()).toBe(undefined);`

Hope that helps.